# How do I replace a capital letter followed by a period with the capital letter only?

Tags: ruby, regex

Anytime a strings contains a capital letter followed by a period, I'd like to replace the capital letter and period with just the capital letter.

```
Today MR. Johnson walked to the mail box.
=> Today MR Johnson walked to the mail box.

William SR. won the race.
=> William SR won the race.
```

I tried to accomplish this using `gsub`:

```
MyText = "William SR. won the race."
MyText = MyText.gsub(/[A-Z]\./,**I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE**]
```

I can match the capital letter followed by the period, but I can't figure out how to replace my match with the capital letter that precedes the period.

Comment: Note you are defining a constant (by starting the word `MyText` with a capital) and the very next line it is changed.

Comment: In both cases, `"MR."` and `"SR."` should be mixed-case, `"Mr."` and `"Sr."` to be correct. Deleting the trailing period only compounds the mis-use of English.

Comment: Tin Man - I agree with on the mis-use of English, however, I receiving the data in a large text file from a third party and have no control of the format. To be fair, I believe the caps are used to call out the particular individual/entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a [positive look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match it and replace it with nothing.

```
MyText = "William SR. won the race."
MyText = MyText.gsub(/(?<=[A-Z])\./, '')
```

Here is an [example](http://rubular.com/r/agdTYfn7Ob) of it on Rubular. You could just use `gsub!` if you know you want to do the replacement in place instead of making a copy.

Comment: But I don't want to replace it with nothing. I want to replace with the capital letter that was in the match.

Comment: You are replacing the period with nothing.  Sorry if that was misleading, the letter will still remain.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Don't you just love Rubular.

Answer (score 7):

An another way without lookaround and using a capture group:

```
MyText = MyText.gsub(/([A-Z])\./,'\1')
```

Comment: @HamZa: And i don't have champagne.